# Node.js writing into an existing excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I’m doing some testing with some node modules to try to insert data into an existing .xlsx template file. I can’t seem to find a module that lets me just insert data into an existing template file. All of the modules essentially let you read a xlsx file into the app, than modify it, and than write it to disk. I need to keep the styling of the xlsx sheet the same while just writing data into specific cells. Whats the best module for this? I’ve tried testing with ‘xlsx’, ‘node-xlsx’, xlsx-writestream’. Is it even possible for Node.js to edit .xlsx files like this ? Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [edit-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-xlsx)?